# Pass by value / reference performance comparison in Maxscript?

Tags: performance, 3dsmax, maxscript

How does it affect efficiency in Maxscript?. 
Maxscript is a slow one, but i wonder how much does it affect?

I tried this script, it took a lot of time to execute the operations in the array, but later on the call to functions were fast returning 0 to the time diference (i tried a very high item count in the array).

```
fn testear lista =
(
    a = 1 + 2
)

fn testear2 &lista =
(
    a = 1 + 2
)

fn inicio = 
(
    lista = #()

    for i = 1 to 1000000 do 
    (
        append lista "hola"
    )

    strTime = timeStamp()
    testear(lista)
    endTime = timeStamp()
    format "\ninicio % final % -> diferencia %\n" strTime endTime (endTime - strTime)

    strTime = timeStamp()
    testear2(&lista)
    endTime = timeStamp()
    format "\ninicio % final % -> diferencia %\n" strTime endTime (endTime - strTime)

    for i = 1 to lista.count do
        deleteItem lista 1

)

inicio()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an array to a function it automatically gets passed as reference. Those two functions are doing the same thing. Try this:

```
fn test1 arr = (
  arr[1] = "test1"
)
fn test2 &arr = (
  arr[1] = "test2"
)
fn init = (
  testArray = #(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
  format "Test #1: %\n" testArray
  test1 testArray
  format "Test #2: %\n" testArray
  test2 &testArray
  format "Test #3: %\n" testArray

)
init()
```

Notice 'testArray' gets changed by the test functions and the change is reflected outside the test functions' scope.

However, array operations can take up a lot of time. When you append to an array, like you do in your code, it basically creates a copy of your array every time you add a new item.

A faster method would be to create an array the size you need initially:

```
lista=#()
lista[1000000] = ""
for i = 1 to 1000000 do 
(
  lista[i] = "hola"
)
```

Deleting every item in the array took the longest, but I don't think you need to do that. Maxscript does a lot of the garbage collection for you so when your script terminates it should free up that memory. Maybe you could try this:

```
for i = 1 to lista.count do
(
  lista[i] = undefined
)
lista = undefined
```

But again, I don't think it's necessary. You can call the built-in garbage collection function:

```
gc()
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Great answers. I haven't tried it yet, but it is useful. What i tried instead is calling those functions a lot of times, but the time was so similar... I'll try this instead.